# Активити создается с нуля при возвращении из нового активити

Tags: android

Есть активити MainActivity, содержащее пару фрагментов прописанных через xml. Также есть еще одно активити, запускаемое из MainActivity. При возвращении из это нового активити в основное происходит следующее: сначала вызывается метод onDestroy основного активити который также убивает все фрагменты, а затем все создается заново как при простом запуске.

Может кто ни будь объяснить мне такое поведение андроида и как тогда сохранить между такими пересоздаваниями состояния активити и фрагментов. Например Текст или изображения, заданные не через xml, а в коде или массив данных?

ЗЫ. Руководствовался [этой](https://ai2-s2-public.s3.amazonaws.com/figures/2017-08-08/9ed2c3f4fa73ba93b0d1d127e4f28a8e869bd455/3-Figure1-1.png) схемой, но вроде бы они все одинаковые в интернете и на всех схемах onDestroy вызывается только при уничтожении активити

```
// Старт приложения
MainActivity.onCreate called

PlayerFragment.onCreate called
PlayerFragment.onCreateView called

PlaylistFragment.onCreate called
PlaylistFragment.onCreateView called

MainActivity.onResume called

// Запуск нового активити
PreferencesActivity.onCreate called

// Жмем кнопку назад
MainActivity.onDestroy called  // Почему это а не onResume?
PlayerFragment.onDestroy called
PlaylistFragment.onDestroy called

MainActivity.onCreate called
PlayerFragment.onCreate called
PlayerFragment.onCreateView called
PlaylistFragment.onCreate called
PlaylistFragment.onCreateView called

MainActivity.onResume called
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если вы делаете переход назад `onBackPressed()` или `finish()` покажите ваш манифест. Исходя из вашего ответа вы выставили определенную стратегию в launchMode, аналогичное поведение было бы если бы у вас стояло

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

или

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

после этого вы заменили на `android:launchMode="singleTop"` и это standart condition, те обычное поведеине со стратегией не создавать новый экземплер если он на вершине стека.

Возмоно также вы делали переход с помощью намерениея Intent, здесь тогда все становится намного сложней. Вам кажется что вы сделали переход назад, но по факту вам ещё нужно следить за PreferencesActivity она у вас ещё в стеке, вы выставили `singleTop` и просто не пересозадил активити с вершиной на стеке, будьте внимательны использую задачи и стек переходов, это очень важно. Вы можете, сделать серфинг по приложению - бесшовным и плавным при этом экономить проц время и объем потреблям трафика.

Здесь есть все для того чтоб понять суть

> https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack?hl=ru

удачи

Comment: собственно поля android:launchMode в манифесте нигде не было, поэтому такое поведение кажется мне слишком странным и неправильным. Также дочернее активити по сути даже не имеет методов кроме onCreate, в остольном это стандартное activity(вообщето AppCompatActivity, но вроде как нет разницы) также не менял onBackPressed(), из дочернего активити возвращаюсь или нажатием физической кнопки назад, или кнопкой назад в статус баре приложения

Comment: дочернее активити создается с помощью ` intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PreferencesActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);`

Comment: тогда или у вас уникальный случай или вы что-то упускаете в коде. кнопка назад в статус баре вызывает onBackPressed ? В целом да из ваших слов если все так, это не стандартное поведение но на практике в 99,9 % оказывается невнимательность

Comment: Ну собственно кнопку добавлял кодом

    ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

Собственно такая кнопка вызывает finish() на дочернем активити. При нажатии же физической кнопки срабатывает onBackPressed как и должно, однако в обоих случаях активити создавалось сначала.

В любом случае спасибо за помощь и статью, которую я не заметил

Answer (score 0):

Это очень странно, но помогло добавление атрибута основной активити *android:launchMode="singleTop"*

После этого система перестала пересоздавать это активити с нуля

Comment: А Вы возврат в неё делаете вызовом `startActivity(<MainActivity Intent>)`?